# Visual Studio Finding out RootSpaceName of a Class in a subfolder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a visual studio website solution with the following structure

A page called Default.aspx in the root folder

and a folder called App_Code in which I have added a class called Test2.vb

I am wondering how I can call the methods from my class Tes2.vb in Default.aspx.vb

I have tried

Dim test1 As New Test2 (Which didnt work)
Dim test3 As New United_Site.Test2 (Adding site name also didnt work)

My Code for Test2 Class

```
Public Class Test2
Public Function ReplaceXSS(ByVal InputString As String) As String
    InputString = InputString.Replace("<script>", "")
    InputString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(InputString)
    InputString = InputString.Replace("</script>", "")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("&", "&#38;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("<", "&#60;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace(">", "&#62;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("%", "&#37;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("|", "&#124;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("$", "&#36;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("'", "&#39;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("""", "&#92;")

    ReplaceXSS = InputString
End Function
```

End Class

and my code for default.aspx

```
Partial Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim test As New Class1 ' Make an object of that class
    Dim test2 As New Spurs ' Make an object of that class
    Dim test3 As New Test2 <--- Error


End Sub
```

End Class

Ok one more thing I noticed is a follows, if I create a brand new folder and a new class I can call it no problems i.e.         Dim test3 As New Test5 and test test5 class is in a folder called "Classes". The issue seems to be my original folder classes called App_Code which is a .NET folder I believe and is grey compared to other folders, I also copied this folder in from a different site.

Comment: Do you have different namespaces for Test2 and Default?

Comment: Hey tim, thanks for replying this is what I am trying to understand i.e. namespaces can you explain what you mean by that question. Both files are created within the same visual studio project

Comment: Visual Studio will by default assign the project name as the namespace (unless you override in the project properties or in the code).  I haven't done a website project in ages, but I'd look at the code for Default.aspx and Test2.vb and see what the namespaces are.  I'm thinking (by default) they should be the same, but if they're not that could be the problem.

Comment: Hey had a look at pages properties I cant see how I can find out in Visual Studio what each files namespaces is ?

Comment: Look at the source code - if you have a namespace, it'll be near the top of the file, before the class.  See @Aristos answer.

Comment: Hey I posted up my full code above

Comment: @Tim let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1650/discussion-between-stevieb-and-tim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably have to do with the namespace declarations.

Check the namespace on the `test2.vb`

if you see something like

```
namespace test2
```

then go to the files that you like to use the functions of the `test2.vb` and add on the first lines

```
Imports test2
```

Also, visualstudio 2010 can help you add automatically this namespace. In the line that you see the error if you move the mouse over you see a red sign that suggest you what to do, for example can suggest to add the **Imports test2**

### Second possible reason

You have an error on your class and they are not have been compiled, so your program can not find them. Check for errors on test2.vb. You can also make rightclick on the solution and select to compile your site to see the messages of errors.

Comment: Hey aristos, how I can find out the namespaces of test2.vb, it doesnt have anything like "namespace test2".

Comment: @StevieB ether have any namespace ?

Comment: Hey i am using Visual Studio 2008. Hey Aristos No i cant see a name space declaration on either

Comment: @StevieB then you probably get an error on the test2.vb and is not compiled.

Comment: I can built my project without errors, so how can I make sure test2 is compiled ? I added my code above

Comment: I haven't done VB.NET in a few years - I thought with VB.NET functions used the Return keyword, rather than the function name = return value syntax of VB?

Comment: @StevieB if you go on your site and right click and make "build web site" did you see any errors ?